# Left join in Django with three models

Tags: django

I am new to Django and I don't know how to do joins. I have the following models and their corresponding tables:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
class ModelB(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    a_id = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    c_id = models.ForeignKey(ModelC, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    extra = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
class ModelC(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

```
ModelA -> Table a: id, name

ModelB -> Table b: id, a_id, c_id, extra

ModelC -> Table c: id, number
```

I would like to perform this left join:

```
SELECT a.*, b.extra, c.number

FROM a

LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id 

LEFT JOIN c ON c.id = b.c_id
```

I don't know how to do that, or if it's even possible.

Comment: It's unclear query the you want to profome.

Comment: Do you actually want to filter ModelA from ModelC. And left joints look less meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

**Relationship** works like below.

```
     ModelB
       /\
      /  \
     /    \
ModelA    ModelC
```

So, `ModelB` is the parent model.

Try your **query** like below.

```
Qa = ModelA.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
Qc = ModelC.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
Query = ModelB.objects.all().filter(a_id__in=Qa).filter(c_id__in=Qc)
```

And when **accessing attributes**, try like below.

```
{% for i in Query %} 

{{ i.extra }} 
{{ i.a_id.name }} 
{{ i.c_id.number }} 

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think `ModelB.objects.all().filter(a_id__in=Qa).filter(c_id__in=Qc) ` is equal to `ModelB.objects.all()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query:

```
ModelA.objects.all().values('id', 'name', 'modelb__extra', 'modelb__c_id__number')
```

but it's better to use a and c instead of a_id and c_id in your ModelB.